# passing double pointer as argument

Tags: c

I wanted to use double pointer. But, please tell me what I did wrong here. The value n does not update after the function called. I am expecting 30 but still see 10.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = 10;
    int *ptr = &n;
    int **ptr2ptr = &ptr;
    function(&ptr2ptr);
    printf("%d", n);
    return 0;
}

void function(int *num) {
    *num = 30; 
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Comment: I think thats a triple pointer. Haven't seen those in a while. :D

Comment: Also, uh, don't forget your function prototype

Comment: Does this code compile? You are passing a triple pointer to a function which takes a single pointer.

Comment: Also, why do you need a double or triple pointer at all? For the example given here, you should be fine with a single pointer. Of course, this might be a simplification of your actual code. If that is the case, it is understandable.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: the function is not declared before the call, obsolete semantics cause implicit declaration of `int function()`, a function taking any amount of arguments of any types, returning an `int`.

Comment: @chqrlie Ahhh...I missed the `c` tag rather than `c++`.

Answer (score 6):

You are actually passing a triply indirected integer to function `function`. `&ptr2ptr` is the address of a pointer to a pointer to an integer. You did not define nor declare `function` before calling it from `main`.  It is incorrect in C99, but supported in ANSI C and implicitly declares `function` to take any number of arguments of any types and returning `int`.  You should move the definition of `function` before `main` and change it to:

```
void function(int ***num) {
    ***num = 30; 
}
```

Comment: Solves the problem with the least amount of change to original code, but also encourages the OP to be a 3 star programmer when he doesn't need to.

Answer (score 3):

You're both passing a triple pointer using `&ptr2ptr` instead of `*ptr2ptr` AND your function takes a pointer and not a pointer to a pointer (`int *` instead of `int **`).

Another way to look at it is that `&ptr2ptr` takes the address of the pointer and it doesn't de-reference it. What you wanted was:

```
function(*ptr2ptr);
```

But to allow you to see more into the mistake, I took the longer route - you can look at this updated code and read through the comments for more info.

Remember, in C: "usage == declaration"

meaning that `*` in a declaration creates a pointer and `*` in usage dereferences (uses) a pointer.

`&` will return the address of the object.

Here's some code to show the difference:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = 10;
    int *ptr = &n; // this is a pointer to an int
    int **ptr2ptr = &ptr; // this is a pointer to the pointer
    // &ptr2ptr is a triple pointer - so we use the double pointer instead.
    function(ptr2ptr);
    // we could have used the original function using:
    // function(*ptr2ptr);
    printf("%d", n);
    return 0;
}

// `int *num ` in your function prototype
// is referencing a pointer to a pointer,
// but it expects a double pointer - updated:
void function(int **num) {
    // *num dereferences the first layer
    // **num references the actual number.
    **num = 30;
    // or:
    // *num = &30; // will fail to compile, unless 30 was a variable
}
```

Comment: *`*num = &30`*  Will indeed fail to compile, and not just because of the missing `;` `;-)`

Comment: @chqrlie  hahaha, that's right :-)  if 30 was dynamically allocated, it would make more sense to use double pointers... But it's a constant number with no address to call it's own, so yeah, it would fail :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are updating the value pointed by the pointer passed to the function,  no need to pass pointer to pointer (you are passing actually pointer to pointer to pointer).
Function `function` expects `int *` type, therefore just pass `ptr`. You have to change the function call

```
function(&ptr2ptr);
```

to

```
function(ptr);
```

Beside this you should have to include function prototype for function `function` or define it before `main`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int** num)
{
    **num = 30;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int n = 10;
    int* ptr = &n;
    int** ptr2ptr = &ptr;
    function(ptr2ptr);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe how your changes answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the good input type for function : int**.

If you add some gcc flags like -pedantic, you will see that you made some mistakes on types.

A working version of your program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int** num);

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int n = 10;
    int* ptr = &n;
    int** ptr2ptr = &ptr;
    function(ptr2ptr);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}

void function(int** num)
{
    **num = 30;
}
```

Note that you don't need a double pointer to do what you want, a simple one is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Let me comment your code for you and explain what is going on:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = 10; //declaring variable n type int

    //declaring variable ptr type int * setting it to address of n
    int *ptr = &n;  

    //declaring variable ptr2ptr as int** and setting it to address of ptr
    int **ptr2ptr = &ptr;

    //now you are trying to take the address of ptr2ptr, which is the address of an int**
    //this gives you an int***, you are passing this in function with undesirable behaviour
    function(&ptr2ptr);
    printf("%d", n);
    return 0;
}

void function(int *num) //take in a parameter of type int*
{
    *num = 30; //dereference it and put value 30 in it
}
```

Instead of calling `function(&ptr2ptr)` you should call `function(*ptr2ptr)` or even better `function(ptr)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's look closely at each line of your code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = 10;
```

`n` is declared as an `int`.

```
    int *ptr = &n;
```

`ptr` is declared as a pointer-to-int and assigned the address of `n`.

```
    int **ptr2ptr = &ptr;
```

`ptr2ptr` is declared as a pointer-to-pointer-to-int and assigned the address of `ptr`. This is what I assume you are calling a "double pointer".

```
    function(&ptr2ptr);
```

Now you send the address of `ptr2ptr` to `function()`. Note that value you are attempting passed to `function()` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to-int (i.e. a "triple pointer").

```
    printf("%d", n);
    return 0;
}

void function(int *num) {
```

`function()` is declared to take a `pointer-to-int`. This means that the function call in `main()` should cause a compiler error since the argument types do not match the parameter types.

```
    *num = 30; 
}
```

As I described above, your code should not compile. You are passing a **triple** pointer (`int***`) to a function which accepts only a single pointer (`int*`).  You have at least 3 possible fixes:

1. Declare `function()` to take a triple pointer:

   ```
   void function(int*** num) {
       ***num = 30; 
   }
   ```
2. Declare `function()` to take a double pointer:

   ```
   void function(int **num) { 
       **num = 30; 
   }
   ```

   and change the function call in main to

   ```
   function(ptr2ptr);
   ```
3. Both of these seem completely unnecessary since you are only trying to change the value of a single `int`. This means you can do all of what you want with a single pointer:

   ```
   void function(int *num) { 
       *num = 30; 
   }
   ```

   Now you can call this function with either

   ```
   function(ptr);
   ```

   or

   ```
   function(&num);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `void function(int *num)` takes 1 argument,and that is a pointer to `int`,so when you call it,you should supply it with the address of an integer,not with address of pointer to `int`,nor address of address of pointer to `int`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = 10;
    int *ptr = &n;
    int **ptr2ptr = &ptr;
    function(&n);
    // function(ptr)  /* this also works */
    printf("%d", n);
    return 0;
}

void function(int *num) {
    *num = 30; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void function(int ***num) {
  ***num = 30; 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int n = 10;
  int *ptr = &n;
  int **ptr2ptr = &ptr;
  function(&ptr2ptr);
  printf("%d", n);
  return 0;
}
```

What you did was give the address of double pointer, so it became triple pointer. Do the above it works fine.

Since code might get complex with triple pointer, just use a double pointer instead of sending address of double pointer:

```
void function(int **num) {
  **num = 30; 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int n = 10;
  int *ptr = &n;
  int **ptr2ptr = &ptr;
  function(ptr2ptr);
  printf("%d", n);
  return 0;
}
```